# " Cannot locate working compiler " in OSX while installing numpy with pip to python 3.3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, numpy, pip

Under **OSX 10.8.5**, I was trying to install the latest version *python 3.3.2* with IDLE and wanted to import package.
I followed the instruction and installed the pip under Library, but face problem while executing the command :  **pip install numpy**

It ends up with showing,

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/_osx_support.py",
>   line 412, in customize_compiler
>
> ```
> _find_appropriate_compiler(_config_vars)
> ```
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/_osx_support.py",
>   line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler
>
> ```
> "Cannot locate working compiler")
> ```
>
> SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler

It seems for me to be a difficult case to install package to python3 on OSX, in order that I could run it on IDLE.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed xcode?

Comment: No.  So is that necessary for me to run python with package on OSX?

Answer (score 1):

You need a C/C++ compiler in order to compile some modules of Numpy. You have to install latest version of XCode.

Comment: Actually, just the command line tools package, not the entire Xcode IDE.

Comment: Thanks, I had it installed.

Comment: Problem is that I am still getting this issue with the latest version of XCode Commandline Tools (March 2014) installed. Any ideas?